# Need to recover Subversion repository database

Tags: svn, repository

I'm currently using svn with Berkeley DB, and just today when I try to 
access the repository I get the error "Could not open the requested SVN 
filesystem".

When I ran "svnadmin recover", I get the following:

```
svnadmin: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
svnadmin: bdb: DB_LOGC->get: LSN 564/955694: invalid log record header
svnadmin: bdb: Skipping log file e:\svn\db\log.0000000368: historic log 
version
10
svnadmin: bdb: DB_LOGC->get: log record LSN 564/955710: checksum mismatch
svnadmin: bdb: DB_LOGC->get: catastrophic recovery may be required
svnadmin: bdb: PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
svnadmin: bdb: PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
```

I've downloaded the Berkley DB binaries, and tried to run db_recover, 
but get the following error:

```
c:\Program Files\Sleepycat Software\Berkeley DB 4.4.20\bin>db_recover 
-vech e:\svn\db
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 565 offset 131910
db_recover: DB_LOGC->get: LSN 564/955694: invalid log record header
db_recover: Skipping log file e:\svn\db\log.0000000368: historic log 
version 10
db_recover: DB_LOGC->get: log record LSN 564/955710: checksum mismatch
db_recover: DB_LOGC->get: catastrophic recovery may be required
db_recover: PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
db_recover: PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
db_recover: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
db_recover: unable to join the environment
db_recover: DB_ENV->open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
```

My issue sounds similar to the one described here:

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2004-08/1341.shtml

So I've deleted the __db* and lot.* files from the db directory, and 
tried to run the above command again, but now db_recover and svnadmin 
recover gives the following:

```
c:\Program Files\Sleepycat Software\Berkeley DB 4.4.20\bin>db_recover 
-vech e:\svn-repair\db
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 1 offset 28

c:\Program Files\Sleepycat Software\Berkeley DB 4.4.20\bin>svnadmin 
recover e:\svn-repair
?w‥u±oAER×RwAecw.
?Dμy?Y; -×’_AER×Rw?]3\±oaa?O?@‥CRE?!...

-×’_§1|‥.
svnadmin: AER×‥t2I 'e:/svn-repair/db' ao Berkeley DB ?u?~, ·i?i|a 
opening 'node
s' table RE:
Invalid argument
svnadmin: bdb: file nodes (meta pgno = 0) has LSN [564][856423].
svnadmin: bdb: end of log is [1][28]
svnadmin: bdb: e:\svn-repair\db\nodes: unexpected file type or format
```

Yes the jibblish characters really do show up.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me recover the database. :(